# How to prevent Chrome and Firefox from consuming vast amounts of memory over long periods of time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I have a long-polling application written in JS fetching XML files to update a web page. It fetches every 5 seconds and is about 8KB of data. I have had this web page open for about 1 week straight (although computer goes to sleep in evening).

When first opening Chrome it starts at about 33K of my PC's memory. After I left it open for a week, constantly updating while the PC was awake, it was consuming 384K for just one tab. This is a common method that my application will be run (leaving the web page open for very long periods of time).

I feel like I am hindering Chrome's GC or am not doing some specific memory management (or maybe even a memory leak). I don't really know how a memory leak would be achievable in JS.

My app paradigm is very typical, following this endless sequence:

```
function getXml(file){
  return $.get(file);
}

function parseXml(Xml){
   return {
      someTag : $(Xml).find('someTag').attr('val'),
      someOtherTag: $(Xml).find('someOtherTag').attr('val')
   }
}

function polling(modules){
    var defer = $.Deferred();

    function module1(){
        var xmlData = getXml('myFile.xml').done(function(xmlData){
           var data = parseXml(xmlData);
           modules.module1.update(data);
        }).fail(function(){
             alert('error getting XML');
        }).always(function(){
            module2();
        });
    });

    function module2(){
        var xmlData = getXml('myFile.xml').done(function(xmlData){
           var data = parseXml(xmlData);
           modules.module2.update(data);
        }).fail(function(){
             alert('error getting XML');
        }).always(function(){
            defer.resolve(modules);
        });
    });

    return defer.promise(modules);
}

$(document).on('ready', function(){

var myModules = {
 module1 : new Module(),
 module2 : new ModuleOtherModule()
}

// Begin polling
var update = null;
polling(myModules).done(function(modules){
   update = setInterval(polling.bind(this, modules), 5000);
});
```

That's the jist of it... Is there some manual memory management I should be doing for apps built like this? Do I need to better management my variables or memory? Or is this just a typical symptom of having a web browser (crome/ff) open for 1-2 weeks?

Thanks

Comment: What do the devtools say about your memory usage? Have you compared memory snapshots?

Comment: No, I will run a profile to see. I was just curious if there was some "typical" situation where this occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems ok but You don't posted what happens on method "udpate" inside "modules". Why I said that? Because could be that method who is leaking your app.
I recomender you two things:

- Deep into update method and look how are you updating the DOM (be careful if there are a lot of nodes). Check if this content that you are updating could have associated events because if you assign a event listener to a node and then you remove the dom node, your listener still kepts in memory (until javascript garbage collector trash it)
- Read this article. It's the best way to find your memory leak: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling